# Trying to upload image from react through a rails API renders Unpermitted parameter: :image error

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, attachment

I am trying to upload an image from React using rails active storage. The problem is I am receiving the following error when making the request,

```
ArgumentError (Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got <ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: false>):
```

The controller with the create action.

```
 def create
    micropost = @current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    micropost.image.attach(params[:micropost][:image])
    binding.pry
    if micropost.save
      render json: micropost
    else
      render json: { errors: micropost.errors }
    end
  end
```

I am using strong parameters.

```
    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :image)
    end
```

This is how the form looks like in the frontend

```
  <input        
    type="file"
    accept="image/*"
    multiple={false}
    onChange={(event) => setImage(event.target.files[0])}
  />
```

The request I make in the frontend.

```
export async function createMicropost(content, image) {
  console.log(image);
  return request({
    url: "/micropost/new",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      micropost: {
        image: image,
        content: content,
      },
    },
  });
}
```

I have also tried replacing `:image` with `image: {}` in `micropost_params`, it stopped rendering the `Unpermitted parameter: :image` error when I used `binding.pry` but the 500 still remained with the same error as in the first image.

Comment: I think your `micropost_params` is not correct, you are permitting `image` there which seems to be an association so it is expecting an object to be assigned to it instead you are assigning it `ActionController::Parameters`. What does your `Micropost` model looks like, what attributes does it have?

Comment: This is it 
`class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :user
        has_one_attached :image
        validates :user_id, presence: true
        validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
        default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
   end`

Comment: What happens if you remove `micropost.image.attach(params[:micropost][:image])` from the action and let it save. Does the `Micropost` does it save the `Image` automatically?

Comment: I solved it, the problem was the request. I was using the basic JSON.stringify method instead of FormData. The answer is to append the content to a FormData object and pass it in the body of the request. Like this: `formData.append("image", image);
  formData.append("content", content);
  return request({
    url: "/micropost/new",
    method: "POST",
    data: formData,
  });`

Comment: You can add it as an answer yourself as well as accept it